# How to sculpt mesh while enabling snap to surface?

Tags: sculpting, snapping, sculpt

In Zbrush, apparently there is a feature where user can sculpt with snap to surface enabled.

Are there any same alternatives that I could try on blender? I want to use this technique to retopologize mesh with an already retopologized mesh (just slightly different).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old.. but if anybody else stumbles across it: TLDR; shrinkwrap modifier.

I have used the sculpt `SHIFT Slide Relax` brush to even out re-topology areas filled with `Grid Fill` or `Bridge Edge Loops` or just quickly filled in by extruding edges and filling with F. The resulting vertices don't necessarily snap to the underlying surface, however it is quick to add and then apply a shrinkwrap modifier.